# Should single scrapy crawler process speed without limit be as fast as multiple crawler processes speed?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS,CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN
and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP to be 1,000,000 but it just cannot be as fast as running multiple crawler processes, each processing part of a list of urls. Is that to be expected? In fact, if I run 8 crawler processes then the speed is about 8x faster.

I am not sure what I am configuring wrong. I would expect a single crawler process without any rate limit to run at the maximum speed possible, so it should be as fast as running 8 crawler processes.

```
import csv
import scrapy
import random
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import re
import json


class XXXSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xxx'

    def start_requests(self):
        

        base_url = 'xxx'
        base_query = 'yyy'

        for s in self.words:
            token = random.choice(self.tokens)
            headers['token'] = token

            user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
            headers['User-Agent'] = user_agent

            params['q'] = base_query.format("${:s}".format(s))
            encoded_params = urlencode(params)
            xxx_url = "{:s}?{:s}".format(base_url, encoded_params)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=xxx_url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
```

multiple crawler processes

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import re
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
import csv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_processes = 32
    pool = Pool(num_processes)
    tokens = pool.map(request_token, range(num_processes))


    concurrency = 8
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    split_size = len(words) // concurrency
    for i in range(0, len(words), split_size):
        split = words[i: i+split_size]
        process.crawl(XXXSpider, tokens=tokens, words=split)
    process.start()
```

Comment: Review: show us your (pseudo) code! It smells like "lock contention", the threads are figting over the same resource in some way. COult it be a limitation of your network bandwidth?

Comment: @H.Hasenack it cannot be because of bandwidth limitation because if that is the case, I wouldn't get speed up from running multiple crawler processes. What setting should I change to remove the "lock contention" ? I have added the pseudo-code, a very simple one.

Comment: you wonder why it is 8x faster in parallel? or why it is NOT faster? If it is faster that makes sense as each thread has to wait for an answer. So you have 8 lines of customers waiting for an answer of 8 employees. It makes sense that this is about 8 times faster as a single line of customers because the bottleneck is probably waiting for the url to resolve server and respond.

Comment: As far as I know, scrapy is multithreaded and each crawler process should be able to create as many threads as it wants, such that there will be no difference between running 8 crawler processes or 1. However, I am not observing that. Does that mean that there is a limit on each crawler process? If so, how can I change it?

Comment: I fear my knowledge stops about here. But it seems to me your iterations of the for loop wait vor scrapy to return after each crawl call, so the requests are not queued but handled one-by-one because you ask them one-by-one. Cant you send a 'block/batch/ of url's to scrapy with onbe call? - then scrapy could resolve them using internal parallel processing. (I am a noob regarding scapy)